# Adding metadata to folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, metadata, directory

Is it possible to add metadata to folders in Windows 7? I would like to see different informations when browsing folders. I.e. if I browse my music folder, I would like to see the release year of that album without stepping into the folder.

Example:

```
Artist1 - Album1 [year = "1973"]
Artist2 - Album2 [year = "1984"]
Artist3 - Album3 [year = "1981"]
```

Some files like images or mp3s can contain metadata, which can be displayed in Windows Explorer, but I need the functionality with folders.

If there is no such solution to use with Windows Explorer, do you know a different filebrowser, where I can see/use tags like that?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a programming question or an end user question?

Comment: It's more an end user question, but if there was a possibility to use that data, it's a programming question, too.